# Swift/iOS Tensorflow lite prediction result returns inconsistent results for image classification

Tags: python, ios, swift, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm new to Swift and Tensorflow lite(Having enough experience with Python and ML). I generated a Tensorflow flow model by Tensorflow in Python for some picture classification task and converted to Tensorflow lite by the converter.

When I try try to call the model from Swift, I succeeded to get the prediction result, but the problem here is no matter what image I specified, I get the totally same prediction result. I'm wondering what could be the cause for this problem. Below you can find my Swift code snippet. The input images are already resized to 224 * 224, so I don't do any image resize task here.

I'm guessing that the root cause of this inconsistent behavor is caused by the below method 'convertUIImageToData'. Maybe the converted Data from the UIImage is not appropriate, but it's too hard for me to figure out why... (Tensorflow lite is working perfectly with the python code. If you need this one, I'll include this later.)

```
func predict() {
    // Path to the TF lite model
    var path = "./Resources/sl_model.tflite"
    
    // Path to the image for classification. The result is samle no matter what the input image is...
    var image = loadImageFromPath(path: "./Resources/bell.png")

    var options = Interpreter.Options()
      options.threadCount = 1

    var interpreter = try? Interpreter(modelPath: path)
    try? interpreter!.allocateTensors()

    // Read TF Lite model input dimension
    let inputShape = try? interpreter!.input(at: 0).shape
    let inputImageWidth = inputShape!.dimensions[1]
    let inputImageHeight = inputShape!.dimensions[2]
    
    // Here try to convert UIImage to Data in order to feed the the input Tensor.
    // Guess this method is not working right...
    let odata = convertUIImageToData(image: image!)

    // Copy the RGB data to the input `Tensor`.
    try? interpreter!.copy(odata!, toInputAt: 0)

    // Run inference
    try? interpreter!.invoke()

    // Get the output tensor
    let outputTensor = try? interpreter!.output(at: 0)

    let results = dataToFloat32Array(data: outputTensor!.data)
    print(results) // This prediction result is always same no matter what the image is...
}
```

```
func loadImageFromPath(path: String) -> UIImage? {
    return UIImage(contentsOfFile:path)
}
```

```
func convertUIImageToData(image: UIImage) -> Data? {
    // Get the CGImage of the UIImage
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
        return nil
    }
    
    // Get the width and height of the image
    let width = cgImage.width
    let height = cgImage.height
    
    // Create a bitmap context using the RGB color space and no alpha channel
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width
    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    var rawData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: width * height * bytesPerPixel)
    
    guard let context = CGContext(data: &rawData,
                                  width: width,
                                  height: height,
                                  bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                                  bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                                  space: colorSpace,
                                  bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue) else {
        return nil
    }
    
    // Draw the image in the context
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    context.draw(cgImage, in: rect)
    
    // Convert raw pixel data to Data
    let data = Data(bytes: &rawData, count: rawData.count)
    return data
}
```

```
func dataToFloat32Array(data: Data) -> [Float32] {
    let count = data.count / MemoryLayout<Float32>.stride
    return data.withUnsafeBytes { (rawBufferPointer) -> [Float32] in
        let floatBufferPointer = rawBufferPointer.bindMemory(to: Float32.self)
        return Array(floatBufferPointer)
    }
}
```

```
// Result: Always same no matter what the input image is...
[3.545041e-08, 0.12145647, 0.008242114, 1.1497581e-09, 0.85731614, 0.012985148, 6.4414756e-08]
```

Below finds you well for my working environment.

- OS: Mac OS 13.4.1 (c)（22F770820d）
- XCode: Version 14.3.1 (14E300c)
- SWift: Apple Swift version 5.8.1
- python3.8.10
- tensorflow==2.13.0
- tensorflow-estimator==2.13.0
- tensorflow-macos==2.13.0

What did I try:

- Executed the predict() method above from Swift playgroud.

What I was expecting:

- If I changes the images, I would get diffrent results for the probabilities...

What I got:

- No matter what the input image is, always got the same result as [3.545041e-08, 0.12145647, 0.008242114, 1.1497581e-09, 0.85731614, 0.012985148, 6.4414756e-08]